# How Can I Root my Sony Ericsson Xperia Tipo Dual?

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-tipo

How can I root my Sony Ericsson Xperia Tipo Dual?

Comment: From where did u get the file? Your question is very unclear..

Comment: I think you're referring to DoomLord's Exploit? Did you unpack all the files, adb installed etc? Did you even consider checking if that works specifically for Sony Xperia Tipo which is only a fairly recent handset?

Answer (score 8):

Newer devices (with newer build numbers) cannot be rooted using the exploit provided by DoomLord, or any other rootkit exploit, without unlocking the bootloader first.

To unlock the bootloader, follow these steps: (This method can also be used to unlock the bootloader for most Sony Ericsson xPeria devices)

**Check if Your Device's Bootloader can be Unlocked**

Some devices that are branded to a network cannot have their bootloader unlocked. To check if your bootloader can be unlocked, follow these steps:

1. Open your dialer app and dial this number: `*#*#7378423#*#*` - It will open a hidden service menu.
2. In the new window that opens, go to `Service info->Configuration->Rooting Status` and look at the bottom of the screen. If `Bootloader unlock allowed` says `No` then you cannot unlock the bootloader, and should stop reading now, if it says `Yes` then your bootloader can be unlocked, and you should read on.

**Install the fastboot drivers**

We now need to install the fastboot drivers so your computer can talk to your device in fastboot mode. You need to do the following:

1. Download the [Android SDK](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r21-windows.exe) and install it.
2. Open the SDK Manager, you need to select platform tools and the Google USB Driver Package for download.
3. Once they have downloaded and installed, download [this zip file](http://dl-developer.sonymobile.com/drivers/downloadinf.zip) and extract it somewhere you can find it.
4. Open the file by double clicking it. Find the part that starts `; SonyEricsson` and copy that and the text below it (stop when you get to the text that next starts with a semi colon).
5. Paste it somewhere below the line that reads `[Google.NTamd64]` (directly below would be best).
6. Save the file, and copy it to the `C:\where\you\installed\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver` directory. Select to overwrite the existing file.

**Get the bootloader unlock code**

1. Go to [this site](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/node/add/ubs-request) and enter your IMEI number (You can only enter 14 digits in that box, so you will have to remove the last digit of your IMEI).
2. You should get your unlock code via email - keep it handy.

**Now to unlock the bootloader (stage 1)**

1. Turn off your device. Hold the volume up button, while connecting the USB cable *with it plugged into the computer*. The LED should turn blue (if there is an LED present).
2. Windows should automatically install the Fastboot driver, if it does not you will have to do it manually via the device manager.
3. Go to the `C:\where\you\installed\sdk\extras\google\`, click the the `usb_drivers` folder, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> at the same time as right clicking, and select the `Open command window here` option. A command prompt will open up.

**Now to unlock the bootloader (stage 2)**

1. In the open command prompt window, type `fastboot.exe -i 0x0fce oem unlock 0xKEY` where KEY is the key you got in the email.
2. Your bootloader is now unlocked, and you can proceed to root using a method such as SuperOneClick or another rooting method.

**WARNINGS**

1. Unlocking the bootloader will almost certainly void you warranty. Sony may charge a fee if they need to replace your device due to new software.
2. Unlocking the bootloader will wipe the device - **ALL** your userdata will be erased. This includes all your downloaded apps, and app data, as well as your contacts. If you synced your contacts with Google they will be restored when you log back in. Your device will be as it was when you first turned it on!

Comment: Could you qualify "newer devices"? What about a 2012 Sony Xperia tipo ST21i?