# How can I root my Sony Xperia Tipo Dual without a PC?

Tags: rooting

I need to root my Xperia Tipo Dual, but I can't connect the phone to a PC, Is it possible to get root without connecting it to a computer?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this question: [How Can I Root my Sony Ericsson Tipo Dual?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35302/how-can-i-root-my-sony-ericsson-xperia-tipo-dual)

The short answer is **no, you need a computer**.

Answer (score -1):

Actually that would be hard as Google has banned applications which provide rooting for device warranty concerns. 
So actually you should search a bit on Google and you may get a site providing easy rooting tools. but you will need a pc.

Comment: It's exciting to have new members to give answers around here! Unfortunately, in this case, the requirement for a computer has nothing to do with a ban on the apps themselves - For example, the CyanogenMod One-click app is still available, just not in the Play Store. But the thing is that those apps **also** require a computer and a companion application to be run on the PC.

Comment: I just talked about the point and that is PC is always needed for rooting, One click app has nothing to do with that.

Comment: However, the requirement for a PC has nothing to do with any ban. It's entirely a technical requirement.

Comment: that was extra information on how onboard rooting applications are not available